# Installing Ubuntu with USB stick

Tags: usb

I tried to install Ubuntu with an usb stick. I used unetbootin. Everytime I tried it, there was an error:

"invalid or corrupt kernel"

I tried with several sticks. What could be the problem?

Greetings from Germany
Michael

Comment: Did you use Unetbootin to download the iso or just to apply it to the USB?

Comment: Maybe download this ISO again, it may be corrupt.

Comment: yes check the md5 hash

Comment: thanks, the checksum was wrong... I will download it again!

Answer (score 0):

If you used that stick to deploy other distrib,
try to clean older install files on the USB stick before applying the ISO (
I personally got problem with old files of previous installation made by Unetbootin).

Comment: Thanks, but didnt work.

Answer (score -1):

To install from a USB stick, just:

1. Download [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)
2. Run Rufus and select your USB stick as the device
3. Click Start
4. Once Rufus is done, reboot to BIOS on the computer you wish to install on
5. Change the boot order to USB first
6. Plug in your USB if it is not still plugged in and cold reboot your computer
7. The computer should boot straight to Ubuntu, from which you can install as if from a disk

I have tried this process and it worked for me. Also, be sure to make sure your checksums match for your iso.

Comment: Do I have to copy the iso on the stick or shall I use unetbootin? Now i got only the iso on it and then it only starts "freedos"?

Comment: Rufus should automatically put Ubuntu on the stick and make it bootable. You should not use Unetbootin for a UEFI system, as it is not UEFI compatible, but if your system does not have UEFI (you should be fine if it is earlier than 2010), then Unetbootin will work fine.